# cannot get my doctors details view to render

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mobile

https://github.com/wramirez09/nx-mobile-alpha.git

I'm using a generator (pets) https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic
I dont know what I'm doing wrong but I'm trying to get a details view wired up. 
in this case its the doctors details page.

please help
https://github.com/wramirez09/nx-mobile-alpha
thanks

Comment: At least put together a runnable test case.

Comment: Needs more info ;} Fiddle + code refs.